# How to Handle Dynamic key Value in JSON Model

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I need to Parse and build dynamic key value json model . in every time key value is different

```
{"product1" :"batch1,batch2","xyzproduct" : "batc265",....,  "productn" : "batch12"}
```

here productn not fixed its any thing value . can someone help how to do in c# or using newtonsoft lib

Comment: Use a `Dictionary<string,string>`.

Answer (score 1):

1. use dictionary

```
var prodDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,string>>(json);

string product1 = prodDict["product1"];
```

2. use dynamic

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,object>>(json);

dynamic products = dict.Aggregate(new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>,
                                (a, p) => { a.Add(p); return a; });
string product1 = products.product1;
```